# Scraping a inner div's text

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in python scraping. For a trial, I was scraping google page searched "cities in Ohio". I want to **scrape** the result i.e. the name of cities which are in boxes with the images (I just want text). Though there are many div so I'm confused that how to go for the div which is having the name of the city that is text. I just want to **scrape** the text written under Columbus. I want that Columbus. And other city's name is also in that div.

Can you please to learn this thing?

```
import bs4
import requests
import html.parser
import lxml,
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN818IN818&ei=KejsXJTSLdu0rQGk3aeQDw&q=cities+in+Ohio&oq=cities+in+Ohio&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.826656.826656..826671...0.0..0.0.0.......0....2j1..gws-wiz.N2bmaS9Bitw')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
type(soup)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
soup.select('.wfg6Pb')[]
```

The output is [] always.
Please use the link in code to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make this work for me I had to do 2 things:

1. add localization to the URL query params (`hl=en&gl=en`) otherwise I got the results in Hebrew (surfing from Israel...)
2. Identify the names themselves with a slightly more specific selector (otherwise I also got some unrelated information blocks)

all in all, my code looks like this:

```py
import bs4
import requests
import html.parser
import lxml
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=en&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN818IN818&ei=KejsXJTSLdu0rQGk3aeQDw&q=cities+in+Ohio&oq=cities+in+Ohio&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.826656.826656..826671...0.0..0.0.0.......0....2j1..gws-wiz.N2bmaS9Bitw')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
city_divs = soup.select('a.Mlb36b div.s3v9rd')
city_names = [c.text for c in city_divs]
```

and output for `city_divs` is:

```html
[<div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Columbus</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Cleveland</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Cincinnati</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Dayton</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Toledo</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Akron</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Youngstown</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Findlay</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Kent</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Chillicothe</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Westerville</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Zanesville</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Wooster</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Elyria</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Hilliard</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Grove City</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Lorain</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Massillon</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Perrysburg</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Strongsville</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Cuyahoga Falls</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Maumee</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Reynoldsburg</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Stow</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Port Clinton</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Pickerington</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Steubenville</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">North Canton</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Gahanna</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Ashtabula</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Beachwood</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">New Philadelphia</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Miamisburg</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Wadsworth</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Bellefontaine</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Painesville</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Put‑in‑Bay</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Worthington</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Twinsburg</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Chagrin Falls</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">North Olmsted</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Barberton</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Canal Winchester</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Wright‑Patterson Air Force...</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Yellow Springs</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Shaker Heights</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Oberlin</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Upper Arlington</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Blue Ash</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Rocky River</div>,
 <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">Pataskala</div>]
```

and for `city_names` is:

```py
['Columbus',
 'Cleveland',
 'Cincinnati',
 'Dayton',
 'Toledo',
 'Akron',
 'Youngstown',
 'Findlay',
 'Kent',
 'Chillicothe',
 'Westerville',
 'Zanesville',
 'Wooster',
 'Elyria',
 'Hilliard',
 'Grove City',
 'Lorain',
 'Massillon',
 'Perrysburg',
 'Strongsville',
 'Cuyahoga Falls',
 'Maumee',
 'Reynoldsburg',
 'Stow',
 'Port Clinton',
 'Pickerington',
 'Steubenville',
 'North Canton',
 'Gahanna',
 'Ashtabula',
 'Beachwood',
 'New Philadelphia',
 'Miamisburg',
 'Wadsworth',
 'Bellefontaine',
 'Painesville',
 'Put‑in‑Bay',
 'Worthington',
 'Twinsburg',
 'Chagrin Falls',
 'North Olmsted',
 'Barberton',
 'Canal Winchester',
 'Wright‑Patterson Air Force...',
 'Yellow Springs',
 'Shaker Heights',
 'Oberlin',
 'Upper Arlington',
 'Blue Ash',
 'Rocky River',
 'Pataskala']
```

Comment: Hello Adam, where did you find these "Mlb36b" and "s3v9rd". I tried but couldn't find in the code after inspecting. BTW I'm targeting < div class="wfg6Pb"> this div to scrap the text.

Comment: When I'm using 
for i in soup.select('a'):
 print(i.text)
it's giving all text on the page under "<a>" and the text I need is also in 'a' but in different div. So is it possible to limit the code to scrap only the text under this < div class="wfg6Pb"> of 'a'

Comment: And parent div of 'a' and < div class="wfg6Pb"> is <div class="uais2d">

Comment: Instead of surfing there myself through my browser (which might take more actions based on scripts and stuff), I just checked what the get response looks like (in Python). I found the div with text "Columbus" and worked my way up from there.

Comment: If you run my code, as-is, do you get different results? it doesn't work for you?

Comment: It worked and gave me the same result as your output. But I want to learn scrap text from inner div. Like use this "for i in soup.select('a'): print(i.text)" and see the output. Among the result, I just want the name of cities, not other stuff. Is this possible?

Comment: BTW finally I did it. It was accidental but yes did it. Thanks for your support.

Comment: it all depends on the specific structure of the web page, and identifying where the data you need is placed. the thing that helped me here is the fact you can have complex selectors with conditions on parents and not just the div you want.